# JVM requirements incompatible error

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, rtc

I have following Java installed:

> Java 32 bit
>
> [image: Java 32 bit]
>
> Java 64 bit
>
> [image]

I have `eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64` installed in my `Windows 7 64 bit` pointing to `jdk1.8.0_05`.

When trying to install IBM software packages (IBM Rational Team Concert Client) using IBM Installation Manager, it gives below error:

> The JVM requirements of the package are incompatible with the JVM java
>   version "1.8.0_05" used by the existing Eclipse IDE

This is my `eclipse.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

What thing that I have misinstalled?

Comment: could you share the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RTC Eclipse client requirement page](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Deployment/CLMSystemRequirements#B4_Eclipse_IDE_RTC_Eclipse_Clien) mentions Eclipse 3.6.x and 4.2.x (Juno) as compatible Eclipse clients.
Kepler (Eclipse 4.3.x) will be for RTC 5.x only.

(Note: accessing the jazz.net wiki requires a jazz.net account: you have to create one, it is free)

That being said, with the latest RTC 4.x, you can try the [process described in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/126301/install-rtc-client-401-to-eclipsejunokepler-fails?redirect=/forum/questions/126301/install-rtc-client-401-to-eclipsejunokepler-fails) which could work even for Juno (4.3):

> - Download an Eclipse release from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/sr2
> - Extract the Eclipse release to c:\tools\eclipse
> - Extend Eclipse by adding a remote update site with the RTC p2repo from ...\RTC\4.x\RTC-Client-p2Repo-4.x.zip
> - When Eclipse has restarted shift to the Jazz Admin perspective

The RTC-Client-p2Repo-4.x.zip file is available on the RTC "all downloads" page, like for instance:

https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0.6?p=allDownloads

Answer (score 1):

You can edit eclipse.ini file like following for java 1.8

```
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 0):

The installation doesn't matter as much as your Environment Path location for Java Compiler.

Try doing a Clean install and stick to the 32 bit installations. I have had issues with 64bit JDK installations.

Comment: Which one that I need to have a clean install? Anyway which Java that my Environment Path should point to? JDK/JRE? 32 bit?

Comment: I always suggest using 32-bit java. But here you have a 64 bit Eclipse so you might want to go with 64 bit version.
I suggest finding the correct one by by trial-error method:
for 32 bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
for 64 bit: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin

Comment: Your eclipse.ini file shows that currently you are using 64 bit Java  compiler. Change the Environment PATH appropriately to match that.
Details: [Extending Eclipse fails with Java VM not found error message, IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21319892)

Comment: **Cause:**
If the Eclipse.ini in your existing Eclipse does not specify a VM, the Installation Manager will search for a VM in the environment PATH variable. However, on Windows, Installation Manager erroneously ignores the first 2 or 4 entries in the PATH during the silent install, thus fails to find the correct VM used by the existing Eclipse.

Comment: My Eclipse has detected the right Java. I think the root of the problem is caused by wrong Eclipse version mentioned by VonC..